# String example doesn't behave as expected

Tags: c

I'm learning C and I've been following the "Head First C" book. I arrived at an example where this is the resulting code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


char tracks[][80] = {
    "I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
    "Newark, Newark - A wonderful town",
    "Dancing with a Dork",
    "From here to maternity",
    "The girl from Iwo Jima", 
};


void find_track(char search_for[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (strstr(tracks[i], search_for))
            printf("Track %i: '%s'\n", i, tracks[i]);
    }
}


int main()
{
    char search_for[80];
    printf("Search for: ");
    fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
    find_track(search_for);
    return 0;
}
```

I've double, triple, and quadruple checked. This code is **exactly** the same as the example in the book. At first I made it my own so that I'm not just copying without learning, but when I didn't work I literally copied it to make sure. The code askes for a string, and then prints any tracks containing the string you gave it. In the book, when the example code is run, the string given was "town", and the code prints "Newark, Newark - A wonderful town." However, when I do the exact same thing it prints nothing but a newline.

I can't stress enough, this code is **exactly** the same as in the book, yet it behaves differently. Can someone see why?

Comment: See `man fgets`: *If  a  newline  is
       read,  it  is  stored into the buffer.*

Comment: You might see the problem if you print the search_for value that was entered.  Putting the string in brackets helps show the problem.
 
 fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
 printf("seeking <%s>\n", search_for);
 find_track(search_for);

Comment: This is a duplicate of 3+ earlier posts - yet IMO, a better answer is here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in this statement

```
fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
```

Function `fgets` includes in the string the new line character.  You have to remove it from the string. For example

```
size_t n = strlen( search_for );

if ( n != 0 && search_for[n-1] == '\n' ) search_for[n-1] = '\0';
```

From the C Standard

Description

> 2 The fgets function reads at most one less than the
>   number of characters specified by n from the stream pointed to by
>   stream into the array pointed to by s. No additional characters are
>   read after **a new-line character (which is retained)** or after
>   end-of-file. A null character is written immediately after the last
>   character read into the array.

Comment: Ok thank you. For some reason however, removing the newlines now prints every track, regardless of what word I pass to the code.

Comment: @user3674736  Due to the new line character the entered string can not be found in the array of strings. So the program displays nothing. The example in the book simply is wrong. You have to add the code I showed.

Comment: That is incredibly frustrating. Your code fixed my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user3674736 Don't worry, be happy.:)

Comment: Just as a side note I also found that just replacing fgets(search_for, 80, stdin), with scanf("%79s", search_for), fixes it as well.